# Fixed button on left screen slider

Tags: jquery

How to implement a button on the left side of a website and when you click it, it will slide a small box to right to show a content. Also, when scrolling down or up, it will stay on the middle left side of screen

Comment: Is it worked for you???

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `slideToggle()` or using `visibility`

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```css
.button{
      background-color : #31B0D5;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-color: #46b8da;
      float:left;
    }
.content{
      float:right;
      display:block;
    } 

    #mybutton {
      position: fixed;
      left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="mybutton">
    <button class="button"  onclick="toggle_visibility('content');">Click here to show content</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
     <div id="content">This is content</div>
</div>
```

Or

```js
$(function()
{
     $("input#toggle").click(function()
     {
         $("#contact").slideToggle();
         return false;
     }); 
});
```

```css
#contact
{
    display: none;
    background: grey;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    float:right;
}
#button
{
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">
    <input type="button" id="toggle" value="Show Content"/>
</div>
<div id="contact">
    This is content!
</div>
```